# Flutter : How to fetch data from API and show in the list form with image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, http

How to fetch data from api .API responses is given below. show in the list form with image in flutter.

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "msg": "7 banners found",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "14",
            "image": "https://www.sofikart.com/admin/upload/app_banner/1635945056.jpeg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "product_id": "81",
            "url": null,
            "status": "Active",
            "ordering": "0",
            "updated": "2021-11-03 06:10:56"
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "image": "https://www.sofikart.com/admin/upload/app_banner/1642082634.jpeg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "product_id": "111",
            "url": null,
            "status": "Active",
            "ordering": "1",
            "updated": "2021-10-28 04:53:26"
        }
    ] }
```

Comment: I don't know if I got what you're needing. You're fetching this result from an API already?

Comment: i want to fetch data from API and design with a list from with image using flutter. Can you help me?

Comment: You know how to call api?

Comment: If you don't know how to call API check out the article here https://paulallies.medium.com/flutter-http-get-json-and-list-4e8b014ee541

Comment: If you don't know how to call api Check @MoklesurRahman comment and if you dont have idea how to make model simple copy your response and paste here https://app.quicktype.io/ make sure select dart language.

Comment: yes i know but i'm new in new in flutter . i want to fetch multiple object from an array 
 and want to show in the list form with image given in responses?

Comment: This is a list of objects. Create a list of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, Flutter has a nice documentation with examples, that I'm pretty sure that will help you.

You can look [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

> Fetching data from the internet is necessary for most apps. Luckily, Dart and Flutter provide tools, such as the http package, for this
> type of work.
>
> This recipe uses the following steps:
>
> 1. Add the http package.
> 2. Make a network request using the http package.
> 3. Convert the response into a custom Dart object.
> 4. Fetch and display the data with Flutter.